# How do you build a ServiceCollection out of a ServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm building a service implementation using this method:

[image: Sample image]

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and am trying to achieve the following:

- Create local ServiceCollection and leave original ServiceProvider (and the underlying ServiceCollection) untouched
- Register the current type (TViewModel) to local ServiceCollection
- Add all services the parent IServiceProvider (built from another ServiceCollection) provides, to the local ServiceCollection.
- use the local ServiceCollection to create a local ServiceProvider, which is able to provide an instance of the type i am currently executing.

Am i doing something crazy here? To me it seems like i am doing something odd here, since the API for it does not exist to initialize a ServiceCollection from another ServiceProvider.

**Note**

I do not want to run serviceCollection.AddX on the original ServiceCollection.

Comment: It's almost certainly not crazy. But when something is off the beaten path it often helps to understand the reason for what you're trying to do. There might be some other suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

> How do you build a ServiceCollection out of a ServiceProvider?

Short Answer: **You can't** out of the box

Once the service provider is built, any changes to the service collection have no effect on the provider.

The [`ServiceProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/DependencyInjection/DI/src/ServiceProvider.cs) class that is eventually built does not expose any way to get the collection that was used to build it.

I would suggest you just keep a reference to the original collection and build a new provider as needed if modifications were made to the original collection.

Otherwise you would need to create your own `IServiceProviderFactory<TContainerBuilder>`

> Provides an extension point for creating a container specific builder and an `IServiceProvider`.

that possesses the functionality you desire.

Comment: explains why this is so difficult - i'll prototype and flag as answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to post that i had a working solution after all:

```
public interface INestedServiceProviderFactory
{
    IServiceProvider FromCurrentScope(Action<IServiceCollection> configuration);
}

public class NestedServiceProviderFactory : INestedServiceProviderFactory

{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public NestedServiceProviderFactory(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public IServiceProvider FromCurrentScope(Action<IServiceCollection> configuration)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var descriptors = GetDescriptors(scope.ServiceProvider);
        foreach (var descriptor in descriptors)
        {
            serviceCollection.Add(descriptor);
        }

        configuration(serviceCollection);

        return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(true);
    }

    private IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> GetDescriptors(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var originType = serviceProvider.GetType();
        if (originType.Name.Equals("ServiceProviderEngineScope"))
        {
            if (originType.GetProperty("RootProvider", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(serviceProvider) is IServiceProvider sp)
            {
                foreach (var serviceDescriptor in GetDescriptors(sp))
                {
                    yield return serviceDescriptor;
                }
            }

            yield break;
        }
        
        var callSiteFactory = serviceProvider?.GetType().GetProperty("CallSiteFactory", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(serviceProvider);
        var descriptors = callSiteFactory?.GetType().GetField("_descriptors", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(callSiteFactory);
        if (descriptors is IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> refDescriptors)
        {
            foreach (var serviceDescriptor in refDescriptors)
            {
                yield return serviceDescriptor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```